# Create durable key in Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, ssis-2012, sql-data-warehouse

In dimension Project, there is business logic that Project Number and Project Name can change over time.
Unfortunately, I cannot get any durable key directly from the source system. Is there a way how to deal with this situation? How to generate Project ID column - in this example is acting as Durable key?

See desired dimension structure.

[image: DimProject]

Project ID - durable key not from source system, I need to generate it.

Comment: Well, outside of the source system, how do you know that these projects are actually the same? If there's no way of knowing, the answer is simple. This info has to be maintained in the source system. As long as you don't provide more information, this is the only answer we can give.

Comment: Surely the source system has an internal key. This is what should be in your dimension

Comment: @Aldo . . . You have no information in the table that ties these four rows together.  Presumably, you could have another set of four rows with the same dates and there is no information on which rows match  one "project".